# append html resultados_pagination datatables doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

With the Plugin [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) i maked my table perfectly. Only have the last problem with this plugin: append html to the id 'resultados_paginate. The problem it's that i can't add buttons, divs, etc.

i use the next code:

```
$('#resultados_paginate').append('<h1>This is a test!!!!!</h1>');
```

the h1 dosen't appear and the html autogenerated it's:

```
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_numbers" id="resultados_paginate">
         <span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">1</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">2</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">3</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">4</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">5</a><span class="ellipsis">…</span><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="resultados" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0"></a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you define an event that trigger your html appending ? When I try your code I do have the expected behaviour (here I am doing the html insertion on document ready) : https://jsbin.com/kapivibisu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: the problem it's because the Datatables plugin stay a 1 sec into insert the trs/divs. Then i was inserting into an inexistent div. The solutión was wait with a settimeout.